# htmlspecialchars output in $_POST

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

Sending login(e-mail adresses) from page 1 to page 2 through $_POST, in order to deal with addresses like jim_o'brien@thing.com.

`echo "<input type='hidden' name='login' value='".htmlspecialchars($_GET['login'], ENT_QUOTES)."'>"`

Looking at page 2 source code, I'm estonished to see it outputs `jim_o'brien@thing.com` instead of `jim_o&#039;brien@thing.com` as I expected to.

I when sending the data again to a new page (page 3) I wrap the login again into `htmlspecialchars($_GET['login'], ENT_QUOTES)` ... and it does what I expect it to do.

But could anyone explain why it loses it's `#039;` encoding in the POST sending ? I can understand it echoes a single quotes in the browser but why does it in source code too?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source of page to see, that in truth it's working fine - in your browser you see "'" because your browser make it "humanable", but after source-look you will see, that everything is fine.

In other way try:

```
echo htmlentities("jim_o'brien@thing.com", ENT_QUOTES);
```

Comment: htmlentities gives the same result. But your answer must be the right one. The browser makes it readable to humans. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, source code does not output `#039;` as a result of  $_POST sending, but a single quote as I first said. I still would like to know why.

Comment: `echo htmlspecialchars("<\"jim_o'brien@thing.com", ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
   echo '<br />';
   echo bin2hex("'");`

What the last one will show you? If other than 27, then that means that it's not really an apostrophe..

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the original question is valid. Here is some code I hacked together in about five minutes. It isn't pretty, and it isn't complicated, but it makes the point.

```
 <?php
 $posted=$_POST[posted];
 if (isset($posted)) {
 echo "POSTED: $posted<br>"; //output: You'll see a quote
 $specposted=preg_replace('/&#039/','****',$posted);
 echo "after entity replace: $specposted<br>"; //output: You'll see a quote
 }
 else{
 $phraseone="You'll see a quote";
 $phrasetest=htmlentities($phraseone, ENT_QUOTES);
 echo "phrasetest: $phrasetest<br>"; //output: You'll see a quote
 $specialphrase=preg_replace('/&#039/','****',$phrasetest); 
 echo "after entity replace: $specialphrase<br>"; //output: You****;ll see a quote
 print<<<HERE
 <form method='post'>
 <input type='hidden' name='posted' value='$phrasetest'>
 <input type='submit' value='GO!'>
 </form>
 HERE;
 }
 ?>
```

Interesting...

Answer (score -1):

`jim_o'brien@thing.com` isn't a valid email adress, and can't be allowed.

Use filter_input for validation.

```
$login = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'login', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL); //or INPUT_POST, if method is POST
if(!$login){
   //invalid e-mail 
}
```

ref.: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filter_input.asp

Comment: Why do you say that's not a valid email address? It is valid.

Comment: Mail adresses containing single quotes are valid, even if Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail ...ect refuse them. As far as validating is concerned I use a regex. But my question was about the output of htmlspecialchars through POST. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Living and learning... I really didn't knew that. I always thought that only letters, numbers, dashes and underlines were allowed. Thanks  (: